# How can I clear out my CruiseControl.Net working directories after a build?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I want to clear out the working directory in a CruiseControl.NET build after the site has been deployed because space is an issue and there's no requirement to keep it.

The way things are set up at the moment everything is on 1 machine (that's unlikely to change), this is acting as both Mercurial repository server, testing web server and CruiseControl.NET build server. 
So on C:\Repositories\ and C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ we have a folder per website. Also in C:\CCNet\Projects we have a folder per website per type of build (Test and Live) - so that means we've got at least 4 copies of each website on the server and at around 100mb per site X 100 sites that's adding up to a lot of disk space.

What I thought I would like to do is to simply delete the Working Directory on successful build, it only takes 5-10 seconds to completely get a fresh copy (one small advantage to the build server being the same machine as the hg server) and only keep a handful of relatively active projects current. Of the 100 or so sites we'll probably work on no more than 10 in a week (team of 5).
I have experimented with a task that runs cmd.exe to /del /s /q the Working Directory folder. Sometimes this will complete successfully, othertimes it will fail with the message that "*The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process*". When it does complete ok the build kicks off again, presumably because the WD is not found and it needs to be recreated, so I'm finding I'm in a never ending loop there.

Are there any ways I can reduce the amount of space required to run these builds or do I need to put together a business case for increasing hosting costs for our servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your own ccnet task and build the logic into it.

1. Create a new project called ccnet.[pluginname].plugin.
2. Use the [artifact cleanup task source](http://ccnet.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ccnet/trunk/project/core/tasks/ArtifactCleanUp.cs?revision=8062&view=markup) as base to get going quickly
3. Change the base directory from `result.ArtifactDirectory` to whatever you need it to be
4. Compile and place `\bin\Debug\ccnet.[pluginname].plugin.dll` to `c:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server` or wherever CCNET is installed.
5. Restart the service and you should be able to use your task in a very similar way as the artifacts cleanup task

Comment: Good idea, but the Artifacts cleanup publisher seems to only work within the artifacts directory and that's at the same level as the Working Directory. I couldn't get it to work on anything outside artifacts.

Comment: @Simon Martin. Shame it didn't work. I guess the only other option is to create your own cc.net task. It's pretty straight forward. I'm just going to update the answer

Comment: Yowser - that's more serious than I thought the solution would be to reduce the amount of space used in creating a build. Might be useful in putting together a business case for more disc space though.

Comment: The new task shouldn't take long to do as you will be extending something that already works. However if you can get more space easily you should go with that and clear the folders manually from time to time. Is the server a physical or virtual machine?